# Wamp - URI don't work as intended

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp, uri

I've encountered quite a odd problem.

I've setup wamp to allow remote connections to my site so they can view it, but
the URI's don't work as intended for other people visiting the site.

When other people uses the navbar on the site the URI don't change but the correct content displays

E.G:

For me: `www.mysite.com/pencils`

Others: `www.mysite.com`

i'm using .htaccess but I don't think that is the problem, i believe the problem is inside wamp somewhere.

But to be sure, here's my .htaccess

//remove .php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

//Always route to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mysite.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Anyone know what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work.

The problem was my web host(provider) which i used to forward my domain and dns to my own server.

I got a different domain service (got a new domain) and used the dns service included from them to point to my server, changed the virtual hosts etc in wamp and then it worked.